# Database solution based on MS Access

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a pretty strange question for you:

At my office, my colleagues save data in a shared Excel document, which crashes very often due to the shared file format, and the many users who use it at the same time.

I tried to create an Access based solution with forms, and it worked pretty well, until it turned out - in the middle of "development", half of my colleagues have x64 OS and the other half have x86 architecture, so most of the VBA code cannot be used - smaller problem - , and the published code is not executable on x64...

My question is: If I build a Windows form that connects to a backend Access database, can I get rid of the x64-x86 problem? Saving to database file will be faster/safer than using the Excel format or I can start everything from scratch after 4 weeks of usage of the access solution? (Probably 20 users max)

And here comes the fun part...I have to cook from what I have :D I have no available SQL server, no Visual Studio at the office... so I have to build a portable WinForm with app configs at home to connect to the access database, saved at our shared network.

What do you think is this possible solution? Or should I try to find a different one?

Many thanks in advance:

Matt

Comment: It is certainly possible to achieve what you are suggesting, be aware of scope creep though, excel has a lot of features that you may be asked to recreate.

Comment: There should also be a feature in Excel, where you connect the worksheet with a database (possibly your access Database). Perhaps this also eliminates the issues with the worksheet. Sounds more like a solution to your problem

Comment: Why use Access at all? Why not SQLite or MySQL etc?